# Automated way to open NodePort range in Network Security Group

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, azure-nsg

I have some pods that have an associated `NodePort` service that I would like to expose to the world. However, I am not in control of setting the value of the `NodePort`, so I need to open up the full range of 30000-32767 in Azure's Network Security Group (NSG).

Manually, I have successfuly created a rule in the NSG, with a destination of the target `Node`'s *internal* IP of `10.240.0.4`. This then allows connection using the `Node`'s *external* IP on the given `NodePort`. So I know it is feasible.

However, I am a little stuck on how to automate the creation of the NSG rule. Typically, you could define a `LoadBalancer` service type, which would cause Azure to create the rule in the NSG and expose it. However this does also mean a different IP is given to the `LoadBalancer`, and in this case, I can't create a `LoadBalancer` for all the `NodePort`s as I am not in control of this deployment.

I've looked at Terraform, and it seems possible to configure an NSG rule; but I can't seem to locate if it's possible to get the target `Node`'s (there are multiple, only one has an external IP) internal IP. This would also not be an ideal solution if we have automatic scaling on the nodes, as new rules would need to be defined.

Am I missing something obvious, where I can instruct the NSG to open any created `NodePort` for a `Node` that is public/is marked as having [`enable_node_public_ip`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster_node_pool#enable_node_public_ip)? The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#assign-a-public-ip-per-node-for-your-node-pools) doesn't add anything further to the public IP information.